# Get the hostname with action script 2

Tags: actionscript-2

I am creating some campaign swf banners and I don't use action script very often so any help from the experts would be great thanks.

I am supplying my banners on my website as resource downloads. And tutorials of how to embed the swf which has some javascript flashvars.

These flash variable is then concatenated into a google campaign link to change the utm_source.

This is my javascript...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var flashvars = {};
    flashvars.campaignSource = window.location.hostname;
    var params = {};
    params.loop = "true";
    params.quality = "best";
    params.wmode = "opaque";
    params.swliveconnect = "true";
    params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
    var attributes = {};
    swfobject.embedSWF("banner.swf", "banner_mpu", "300", "250", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

and my html...

```
<div id="banner_mpu">
    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
    </a>
</div>
```

So the above js works great, however, not everyone will use my tutorial code and will probably use there own methods to embed the swf banner on their site.

So I need some back up action script 2 to get the current hostname into a action script variable

This is my action script which I have so far on my button (swf)...

```
on(release) {

    function GetTheHostname() {

        var RootFullUrl = _root._url;
        txtFullUrl.text = RootFullUrl;
        var lastSlashIndex:Number = RootFullUrl.lastIndexOf("/");
        var DriveIndex:Number = RootFullUrl.indexOf("|");

        if (DriveIndex>=0) {
        baseUrl = RootFullUrl.substring(0, DriveIndex);
        baseUrl += ":";

    } else {

        baseUrl = "";

    }

        baseUrl += RootFullUrl.substring(DriveIndex+1, lastSlashIndex+1);
        txtBaseUrl.text = baseUrl;
        return baseUrl;

    }

    var campaignSourceAS2:String= GetTheHostname();

    if ( _root.campaignSource == undefined ) {

        getURL("http://www.mysite.co.uk/?utm_source=" + campaignSourceAS2 + "&utm_medium=MPU&utm_campaign=My%20Campaign%202012", "_blank");

    } else {

        getURL("http://www.mysite.co.uk/?utm_source=" + _root.campaignSource + "&utm_medium=MPU&utm_campaign=My%20Campaign%202012", "_blank");

    }

}
```

The problem with my action script is that it returns the full current URL.

Can any one please help me adapt the GetTheHostname function to get the host name instead of the baseURL

Thanks in advance

Comment: The code seems to run fine. What is the _root.url and what url are you expecting to get from your GetTheHostname method?

Comment: Indeed the code runs fine. But the actionscript retrieves the full base URL - Lets say for example a web banner lives here.. `http://example.com/category/actionscript` and my script about will return this.. `http://example.com/category/actionscript` - I could really do with the action script GetTheHostname() function to return the same value as what the flashvar would return. The flashvar returns this.. `example.com` So basically the javascript `window.location.hostname;` but I need it in action script. I don't think there is a pre-made function that does this in actionscript 2. Thanks

Comment: `GetTheHostname()` currently gets `http://www.example.com/category/actionscript` but I would like `www.example.com` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, I guess it would be as easy as stripping the http:// from the url and then get all that's left to the first /

A one-liner to go from 'http://www.example.com/category/actionscript' to 'www.example.com' would be

```
var baseURL:String = _root._url.split("http://").join("").split("/")[0];
```

and to replace your full method

```
getURL("http://www.mysite.co.uk/?utm_source=" + (_root.campaignSource || _root._url.split("http://").join("").split("/")[0]) + "&utm_medium=MPU&utm_campaign=My%20Campaign%202012", "_blank");
```

Comment: Nice dude - thanks for showing me this. Though what happens if it is on https:// - is there anyway to find the first // and spilt it from there? Appreciate your help Will.

Comment: var baseURL:String = url.split("//")[1].split("/")[0]; This only works if there are no other double slash occurrences within the url.

Comment: `.split("://")[1].split("/")[0];` worked like a beauty. Thanks for all your help. Josh